# How to use dataProvider against multiple testng method using selenium testng code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, testng, testng-dataprovider

could you please suggest what could be the issue with my code , After using **dataprovider** my test method **Test2** and **Test3** both are looks like unreachable,**can you provide me the solution that how i could fix this issue without putting all the code into single Test method**

1. while using data provider i'm only able to reach Test1 code means after executing my code i am getting below output  (see below output)

OUTPUT

**Before Test case**

**Print Test1**

where my expected output should be (see below out put)

OUTPUT

**Before Test case**

**Print Test1**

**Print Test2**

**Print Test2**

```
public class Test extends DriverConfig {
    
    @DataProvider
    public Iterator<String> getTestData() throws Exception {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(12, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        ArrayList<String> getclientProduct = sftpCon.clientProduct("Client Type");
        System.out.println("getclientProduct----------" + getclientProduct);
        System.out.println("Before Test case");
        return getclientProduct.iterator();
    
    }
    
    @Test(priority = 1, retryAnalyzer = com.brcc.tool.RetryFailedTestCases.RetryTestCases.class,dataProvider = "getTestData")
    public void A1(String clientName,String clientAddress) throws Exception {

        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Print Test1");
    }
    @Test(priority = 2, retryAnalyzer = com.brcc.tool.RetryFailedTestCases.RetryTestCases.class)
    public void A2() throws Exception {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 80);
        System.out.println("Print Test2");
        
    }

    @Test(priority = 3, retryAnalyzer = com.brcc.tool.RetryFailedTestCases.RetryTestCases.class)
    public void A3() throws Exception {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        System.out.println("Print Test3");
        
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use BeforeClass annotation to execute a code before all test methods. driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(12, TimeUnit.SECONDS); shall not be inside DataProvider. DataProvider is automatically called from test methods when the name is used within the Test.

Comment: It's not working , i have multiple test data to be testing where my code flow should be multiple times as per my test data but I don't know where is the issue i can able to get only the result of 1st test data not 2nd and 3rd .... etc

Answer (score 0):

Name of of the data provider was not defined in the code. Name of the data provider should match with the name used within @Test

```
@DataProvider (name = "getTestData")
```

Following should work with the expected order of execution.

```
public class Test extends DriverConfig{


@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass(){
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    System.out.println("Before Test case");
}

@DataProvider (name = "getTestData")
public Iterator<String> getTestData() throws Exception {
   
    ArrayList<String> getclientProduct = sftpCon.clientProduct("Client Type");
    System.out.println("getclientProduct----------" + getclientProduct);
   
    return getclientProduct.iterator();

}

@Test(priority = 1, retryAnalyzer = com.brcc.tool.RetryFailedTestCases.RetryTestCases.class,dataProvider = "getTestData")
public void A1(String clientName,String clientAddress) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Print Test1");
}
@Test(priority = 2, retryAnalyzer = com.brcc.tool.RetryFailedTestCases.RetryTestCases.class)
public void A2() throws Exception {
 
    System.out.println("Print Test2");

}

@Test(priority = 3, retryAnalyzer = RetryFailedTestCases.RetryTestCases.class)
public void A3() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Print Test3");

}
```

}

Comment: I tried with @DataProvider (name = "getTestData") , but still it's not working for me

Comment: 1. Did you add the @BeforeClass section? 2.  Why do you have wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); It does not do anything at the moment.  3. Your DataProvider output should match with the parameters in the Test methods. https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Factory annotation for these type of scenarios.
Below is the code snippet

```
public class Test{
        
    String data;
    
    @DataProvider(name="dataProvider")
    public static Iterator<String> getTestData() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        data.add("Test Data");
        return data.iterator();
    
    }
    
    @Factory(dataProvider="dataProvider")
    public Test(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void A1() {
        System.out.println("Print Test 1: " + data);
    }
    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void A2() {
        System.out.println("Print Test 2: " + data);
    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void A3()  {
        System.out.println("Print Test 3: " + data);
    }
        
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Print Test 1: Test Data
Print Test 2: Test Data
Print Test 3: Test Data

===============================================
Single Test
Total tests run: 3, Passes: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: can you provide an example, My expected output should be Print Test 1: Test Data1
Print Test 2: Test Data1
Print Test 3: Test Data1                                                                                                    
Print Test 1: Test Data2
Print Test 2: Test Data2
Print Test 3: Test Data2                                                                                                    
Print Test 1: Test Data3
Print Test 2: Test Data3
Print Test 3: Test Data3

Comment: In your dataprovider function, just add more elements in the array list

`@DataProvider(name="dataProvider")

    public static Iterator<String> getTestData() throws Exception {
       ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        data.add("Test Data 1");
        data.add("Test Data 2");
        data.add("Test Data 3");
        return data.iterator();
    
    }`

Comment: Could you please correct this method , looks like return type is missing for this method.@Factory(dataProvider="dataProvider")
    public Test(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }